# A JTAG emulator for use with a Hawkboard and OpenOCD?

Tags: gdb, arm, jtag, openocd

I'd like to try bare metal ARM programming with the [Hawkboard](http://www.hawkboard.org/), but the deployment process looks awful. I'm totally new to this, so I could be misunderstanding the instructions, but it appears that I have to use a program called AISgen to convert the binary file, then boot with u-Boot over UART and copy the AIS binary into memory. Not only is that a lot of stuff to do every time I make a change, it also doesn't give me the ability to debug with GDB.

The best solution for this that I can find is JTAG. But the prices for these JTAG emulators look ridiculous. I'm not even sure which ones will work with the Hawkboard and which ones won't. So far, my best bet appears to be the [Flyswatter](http://www.tincantools.com/product.php?productid=16134&cat=0&page=1&featured), but the pin layout is different.

Basically, I need something that's relatively cheap and works with the Hawkboard and OpenOCD.

Any suggestions? Or is there another way I could do this, perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See:
http://groups.google.com/group/hawkboard/browse_thread/thread/4fe68bf3b7bbfc07/d0ec4d52d1d7a0f5?show_docid=d0ec4d52d1d7a0f5

Comment: I read through that a while ago, but ignored the XDS100v2 because it was for CCS and not OpenOCD/GDB. But I see now that CCSv4 is free as long as it's only used with the XDS100v2. That's pretty handy, especially considering the Hawkboard uses a TI processor anyway.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.etoolsmiths.com/blog/jtag-boundary-scan-vs-jtag-emulation-ice/